# How to get rate of requests for a service in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to Kubernetes, and planning on moving some of my ECS services to EKS. In my current auto-scaling algorithm, apart from CPU, memory and some other things I also used rate of incoming requests. In Kubernetes, how can I leverage rate of incoming requests to customize auto-scaling?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **Prometheus** adapter along with the HPA to scale the deployment based on incoming requests or other metrics you want.

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/prometheus-adapter/blob/master/docs/walkthrough.md

also do check this out : https://github.com/zalando-incubator/kube-metrics-adapter

**Example**

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: myapp-hpa
  annotations:
    # metric-config.<metricType>.<metricName>.<collectorType>/<configKey>
    metric-config.pods.requests-per-second.json-path/json-key: "$.http_server.rps"
    metric-config.pods.requests-per-second.json-path/path: /metrics
    metric-config.pods.requests-per-second.json-path/port: "9090"
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: myapp
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 10
  metrics:
  - type: Pods
    pods:
      metric:
        name: requests-per-second
      target:
        averageValue: 1k
        type: AverageValue
```